# Firefox renders a gap over a css round corner div

Tags: html, css

Look at this pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/BAEcp in Firefox 21 over the div with the round corners there is a gap which is not in Chrome 27 or IE10.

What is that gap? When I remove the roundArea class and add height percent value to one of the other divs to get in sum 100% the gap is removed.

```
<div id="chartBody">
      <div style="border:black solid 1px;">
        <figure>              
          <div class="push-center" style="height:25%;">1th test</div>
          <div class="push-center" style="height:50%;">2nd test</div>
          <div class="push-center" style="height:25%;">3rd test</div>
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
          <div class="push-center"></div>
        </figcaption>
      </div>

      <div>
        <figure>
          <div class="push-center roundedArea" style="background-color:#fff;height:22%;"></div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff99cc;height:11%;">3</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff33cc;height:44%;">44</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff66cc;height:23%;">36</div>
        </figure>
        <!-- data-bind="text: title" -->
        <figcaption>
          <div class="push-center">ak</div>
        </figcaption>
      </div>      
    </div>
<div id="chartFooter">
      <div class="push-center">tests</div>
      <!-- foreach: denies -->
      <!-- data-bind="text: deny" -->
      <div class="push-center">6</div>      
</div>



body, html,figure,figcaption{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:arial; 

}

*{ /* Every element which has a border or padding value puts this value inside the div */
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.push-center
{   
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;  /* FF fix */
  text-align:center; /* FF fix */
}

#chartBody{
  background-color:white;
  height:90%;
}

.roundedArea{
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: gray dashed 1px;  
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}

.diagram
{
  color:white; 
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom:white solid 1px;
}

figcaption div{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  height:100%;
}

figcaption{
  height:10%;
}

figure {
  height:90%;
}

#chartBody > div  {
  height:100%;  
  float:left;
}

#chartBody > div:nth-of-type(1), #chartFooter > div:nth-of-type(1)
{
  margin-left:10px;
}

#chartBody > div:nth-of-type(n+1), #chartFooter > div:nth-of-type(n+1)
{
  width:80px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

#chartBody > div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div, #chartFooter > div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div
{
  width:40px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

#chartFooter{
  padding-top:5px;
  height:10%;
  border-top:#000 solid 1px;  
}

#chartFooter div{   
  float:left;
}
```

see this image for the gap:

[image]

Comment: Can't replicate that bug in FF 21. Looks fine to me, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @Duniyadnd yes I have updated my question with an image :)

Comment: The 'AK' on the bottom is also misplaced, quite strange.

Comment: @Adrift yes thanks for that finding I agree. When I resize my window smaller the AK flows into the above div with "36" which happens not in Chrome27/IE10.

Comment: The round corners don't seem to have anything to do with it.  I changed the div to have the diagram class and the same gap is shown.

Comment: gets fixed when you remove the `display: -moz-box;` from the `.push-center` rule, which according to the MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex) is superseded and should not be used..

Comment: but when I remove this property then all numbers are not vertically aligned anymore. There seems also to be another "bug" although the text was horizontally aligned when I do not set this: text-align:center; /* FF fix */ then nothing is centered horizontally although the box align should do. It works in Chrome/IE...

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli They just warn the developer that the moz will be replaced with the css3 specification and to me it seems they have not done it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.push-center needs "vertical-align: top;".

In Firebug you can see that the space is the space between the top of figure and the top of .push-center .roundedArea.

Comment: You found to fix a symptom, but what is the cause because in Chrome/IE it works without that!

Comment: I think you will find the exact answer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes.

When some of the specific properties are not set (flex-direction may be the guilty property in your example), I think FF probably specifies a default to distribute elements from the middle of the vertical axis instead of from the top. So my guess is that in your example, .push-center elements as a group are centered from the middle of the 90% container space, but because they are different heights, you get an offset at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block;` to `.push-center` and that gap will go away.

Comment: When I do this then the whole layout/alignment is broken. That is not a solution.